# regex works, but fails in case sensitive cases

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the below in javascript, it works for this case;

```
http://www.google.com


/(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g
```

but it fails for this:

```
Http://www.google.com
```

is there a way to make my statement case insensitive.

Comment: Just add the `i` flag at the end

Answer (score 7):

You can add `i flag` for ignore case matching:

```
/(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/ig
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the votes are in for adding the `i` flag (which is a perfectly valid solution), I would point out that it is a bit more efficient to leave your regex as is and call `toLowerCase()` on your string prior to running it through the regex IFF that is an option.

```
var uri = "Http://www.GooGlE.cOm";
console.log(uri.toLowerCase().match(/(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

use following line

```
/(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/i
```

/g enables "global" matching. When using the replace() method, specify this modifier to replace all matches, rather than only the first one.
/i makes the regex match case insensitive.
/m enables "multi-line mode". In this mode, the caret and dollar match before and after newlines in the subject string.